# Busy Indicator for multiple async calls

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I have a `Busy` property that is set to true before an async call is made, then set to false when finished. Now I have 2 async calls, how do I handle this logic? Do I need to lock variables or some other parallel problems I need to look out for?

```
private bool _busy;

public bool Busy
{
    get { return _busy; }
    set
    {
        bool changed = value != _busy;
        _busy = value;
        if (changed) RaisePropertyChanged("Busy");
    }
}

private void loadUser(int userId)
{
        Busy = true;
        api.GetUser(userId, CancellationToken.None).ContinueWith(t =>
                                      Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                      {
                                          Busy = false;
                                      }));

}

private void loadOtherData(int dataId)
{
        Busy = true;
        api.GetData(dataId, CancellationToken.None).ContinueWith(t =>
                                      Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                      {
                                          Busy = false;
                                      }));

}
```

I know this logic is flawed due to the Busy property is set to false on the first method that finishes execution. An idea I have is to use 2 more fields; `isUserLoading` and `isOtherDataLoading` and ensure both are false before setting `Busy` to false.

I'd like to know if there is a better way of accomplishing this.

Comment: I've been using a numeric counter (which your async calls will increment/decrement) with a property like bool Busy { get { return _count != 0; } }. I'm curious to see what others recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two booleans, `_isUserLoading` and `_isOtherDataLoading`, that you update in your load methods, then you can just change `Busy` to this:

```
public bool busy
{
    get
    {
         return _isUserLoading || _isOtherDataLoading;
    }
}
```

---

Another version including the call to RaisePropertyChanged could work like this:

```
public bool busy
{
    get
    {
         return _isUserLoading || _isOtherDataLoading;
    }
}

public bool IsUserLoading
{
    get
    {
         return _isUserLoading;
    }
    set
    {
       bool busy = Busy;
       _isUserLoading = value;
       if (busy != Busy) RaisePropertyChanged("Busy");
    }
}
```

And of course a similar property for `IsOtherDataLoading`.

Comment: Do I have to worry about locks on the Busy property?

Comment: How would I also handle it for a notifyproperty? I edited my question

Comment: See my edit above for one way that you could include the RaisePropertyChanged call

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to expose an observable property/event from the API stating when it's busy. Asuming you can't make any modifications, I'll suggest you go with a more generic approach. Something like

```
class CountedContext {
    int workersCount  = 0;
    Action<bool> notifier;  

    public CountedContext(Action<bool> notifier) { this.notifier = notifier; }

    public Task<TResult> Execte<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
    {   
        lock(worksersCount) 
        { 
            workersCount++; 

            if (workdersCount == 1)
                notifier(true);
        }

        var result = func();

        result.ContinueWith(_ => 
        {
            lock (worksersCount)
            {
                workersCount--;

                if (worksersCount == 0){
                    notifier(false);
                }
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

In your main class you can use:

```
// constructor:
countedContext = new CountedContext(state => 
{
    ...BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        Busy = state;
    });
});

...

// loadData
countedContext.Execute(() => api.GetData());
```

Comment: You could use a similar technique but more embedded in the API